# Proof of uniqueness of Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I was reading a proof on the uniqueness of the Taylor series expansion, but I'm struggling with a part of the proof. The proof goes as follow:

Consider 2 possible expansions $f(x)=f_0+f_1(x-x_0)+...$ and $g(x)=g_0+g_1(x-x_0)+...$. Let's prove it by contradiction, saying that all coefficient are equal up to an index k for which $f_k \neq g_k$. We can now say that since they are both correct expansions $f(x)-g(x)=0=[f_0+f_1(x-x_0)+...+f_k(x-x_0)^k+...]-[g_0+g_1(x-x_0)+...+g_k(x-x_0)^k]$.

Cancelling the terms before k, that are equal by assumption we get $0=(f_k-g_k)(x-x_0)^k+(f_{k+1}-g_{k+1})(x-x_0)^{k+1}+...$, taking the first term to the other side and dividing by $(x-x_0)^k$ we get that $f_k-g_k=(f_{k+1}-g_{k+1})(x-x_0)+...$. Now if we watch how this behave under $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}$ we see that the right side goes to $0$. So we get the absurd $f_k-g_k=0$, since we supposed they were different.

The part that I don't get is when we divide by $(x-x_0)^k$, isn't that like dividing by $0$? And this make possible weird things like saying different things are equal.

I could say $0=(1-2)(x-x_0)+5(x-x_0)^2 \Rightarrow (2-1)=5(x-x_0) \Rightarrow 1=0$ that doesn't make sense.

Could someone clarify?

Comment: How is $f(x)=g(x)$?

Comment: @Rahul it's what has to be proven by the theorem, that the expansion is unique. In the proof we just say there are two different expansions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that approximate the same function, and so are equal, but with different coefficients, leading to the absurd.

Comment: I guess you want to say two expansions of $f(x)$, Here $g(x)$ looks like different function.

Comment: ye, I thought it was clear by the text, btw I found the error, my second miniproof was wrong cause the two expansions doesn't rapresent the same equation, thus they are not equal to $0$ but equal to $o(1)$, and that $o(1)/(x-x_0)$ goes to -1 and fixes everything. Thanks anyways

Comment: Remember that $\lim_{x\to x_0}$ considers values of $x$ that are close to, but not equal to, $x_0$. Therefore $x-x_0$ is never equal to $0$ as far as the limit is concerned, and so there is no dividing-by-zero problem.